# Restoring OS X Server Data from Time Machine

Tags: time-machine, restore, osx-server

How does one restore OS X Server data from time machine on another server?

I had a Mac mini with OS X Server (Mountain Lion). It had Time Machine backups and this weekend the server experienced a hardware problem. I'm trying to migrate the server to another server. When trying to restore it on another machine, I get the following error.

[image]

I then installed OS X Mountain Lion 10.8 and OS X Server and then tried to restore the `/Library/Server` folder to the new machine. Unfortunately, this failed because some folders are locked.

Comment: Is this using restore ot Migration Assistant?

Comment: No, I simply booted from a recovery disk and selected to restore from a Time Machine backup.

Answer (score 1):

The KB article HT5139 ["Restoring OS X Server from a Time Machine backup"](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5139) describes how to restore OS X Server (Mountain Lion) or Lion Server from a local Time Machine backup:

> The steps to restore from a Time Machine backup depend on whether your
>   data was stored on the startup (boot) volume or a non-startup volume.
>
> **Important:** When restoring, restore from a *local* Time Machine backup. If you try to restore from a network-based Time Machine
>   backup, not all settings will be restored correctly.
>
> (...)
>
> **Time Machine is the native backup service for OS X Server. OS X Server
>   also includes a process called ServerBackup which works with Time
>   Machine.** ServerBackup performs daily backups of Open Directory (if it
>   is enabled) and the Postgres databases used by the Calendar (or iCal),
>   Contacts (or Address Book), Profile Manager, and Wiki services. These
>   daily backups are included in the Time Machine backup of Lion Server.
>   ServerBackup also takes part in the restoration of server services,
>   running during the first startup after a server has been restored, and
>   restoring server services and databases into place after the server
>   has started up.

From [KB article HT5139](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5139):

If server data was on the startup disk proceed as follows:

1. Make sure your *local* Time Machine backup drive is connected.
2. Start up your server using OS X Recovery by holding down <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>.
3. Select Restore from Time Machine Backup and follow the onscreen instructions for restoring the volume.

Otherwise:

1. Make sure your *local* Time Machine backup drive is connected.
2. Start up your server using OS X Recovery by holding down <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>.
3. If your Time Machine drive is encrypted:

   - Open Disk Utility, then click Continue.
   - Control-click or right-click the Time Machine volume, then select "Decrypt".
   - Enter the volume password and click OK.
   - Create or make sure that you have a new service data volume that is large enough to store your previous data and has the same name as your previous service data volume.

     For example, if your service data was stored on a 500 GB volume named "DataHD", make sure you have a new volume of at least 500 GB named "DataHD".
   - Quit Disk Utility.
4. From the Utilities menu, choose Terminal.
5. Enter the following command on one line.

   Replace Time Machine Backup Disk with the name of your Time Machine backup disk, servername with the name of your server, and Startup Volume Name with the name of your previous startup volume.

   `cd /Volumes/Time Machine Backup Disk/Backups.backupdb/servername/Latest/Startup Volume Name/`
6. Enter the following command on one line. Replace Service Data Volume with the name of your original (and future) service data volume.

   `./usr/bin/tmutil restore -v ../Service Data Volume/* /Volumes/Service Data Volume`
7. Quit Terminal.
8. If you also need to restore the startup volume, select "Restore from Time Machine Backup" and follow the onscreen instructions.

**I realize that you tried the first option and it failed with a model mismatch error. You may want to try the second option.**

Comment: Unfortunately, the Migration Assistant ignores around 10GB of server data. So mail, calendar, contacts etc isn't being restored.

Comment: Do take into account that the Server app adds additional steps to restore PostgreSQL etc when restoring from Time Machine.

Comment: I found out that Migration Assistant is used with the client version of OS X. OS X Server must be restored following a different procedure, that's why some data wasn't restored. I've edited my answer accordingly, please take a look.

Comment: I'm afraid that these steps do not work when the new mac mini model is vastly different. Some preferences are restored, but none of the users, mail, postgres data...

Comment: BTW. Its best just to link to the page and describe why you think it may be the answer, rather than copying it here.

Comment: **I'm afraid that these steps do not work...**: I'm sorry about that. **Its best just to link to the page...**: As a matter of fact, I did both: I linked and quoted KB article HT5139. Edited my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: @WernerStrydom- On AskDifferent we want answers to be here and not rely on a link

Comment: I guess its different than stackoverflow. My mistake. When we answer programming questions (which I have done a bit), a link is sufficient and a remark as to why it may answer the question is in order. After all, the information at the link can be revised, while its unlikely the answer will be revised.

Comment: I'd rather have someone who has experience answering the question (not to take anything away from jaume). After all, shouldn't we post a question here after doing our own research? The link provided is #2 on google and yes, I did try it amongst several other steps (including running ServerBackup). The danger with these types of answers are that folks would post any question, even if the answer is self-evident. On stackoverflow its seems to be expected that you do some research before asking the question. If the answer is #2 on Google, chances are you'll be down voted.

Comment: @WernerStrydom I understand, but it was not apparent from your answer and comment (*No, I simply booted from a recovery disk and selected to restore from a Time Machine backup.*) that you had read KB article HT5139. I'd suggest that in the future (and why not, now) you add to your questions any research you've done what you have tried. It will save both you and people willing to help time and also prevent disappointment. Anyway, I hope someone with *actual* experience will chime in. Good luck!

Comment: @jaume  I appreciate the answer and made the remark after carefully rereading the article and trying variations of it. There is nothing wrong with the answer per se, other than in my opinion, a link would have sufficed and why you think it may solve my problem.

Comment: It turns out that you can only restore a Time Machine backup on the same machine that made the backup. It will not restore a backup to a new physical machine even if the hardware is of the same kind. You have to use the Migration assistant. The root of the problem is that the latter doesn't migrate server data. I have escalated it to Apple, but don't expect it to be addressed soon.